# Why rvalue reference binding to xvalue doesn't work in my code?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue, lvalue, xvalue

I tried to understand lvalue and rvalue in C++11. So I wrote a test code:

```
int x = 10;
int foo() { return x; }
int& bar() { return x; }
int&& baz() { return 10; }

int main() {
    int& lr1 = 10;     // error: lvalue references rvalue
    int& lr2 = x;      // ok
    int& lr3 = foo();  // error: lvalue references rvalue
    int& lr4 = bar();  // ok
    int& lr5 = baz();  // error: lvalue references rvalue

    int&& rr1 = 10;    // ok
    int&& rr2 = x;     // error: rvalue references lvalue
    int&& rr3 = foo(); // ok
    int&& rr4 = bar(); // error: rvalue references lvalue
    int&& rr5 = baz(); // ok
}
```

It works pretty well, so I inserted std::cout to print results.

```
#include <iostream>

int x= 10;
int foo() { return x; }
int& bar() { return x; }
int&& baz() { return 10; }

int main() {
    int& lr1 = 10;     std::cout << lr1 << std::endl; // error
    int& lr2 = x;      std::cout << lr2 << std::endl; // ok
    int& lr3 = foo();  std::cout << lr3 << std::endl; // error
    int& lr4 = bar();  std::cout << lr4 << std::endl; // ok
    int& lr5 = baz();  std::cout << lr5 << std::endl; // error

    int&& rr1 = 10;    std::cout << rr1 << std::endl; // ok
    int&& rr2 = x;     std::cout << rr2 << std::endl; // error
    int&& rr3 = foo(); std::cout << rr3 << std::endl; // ok
    int&& rr4 = bar(); std::cout << rr4 << std::endl; // error
    int&& rr5 = baz(); std::cout << rr5 << std::endl; // ERROR!?
}
```

`int&& rr5 = baz(); std::cout << rr5;` causes a Runtime Error, but I don't know why it makes an error.

I think the return value of `baz()` would be xvalue, so its lifetime is prolonged. But when I tried to access its value, the error occurs. Why?

Comment: When asking questions about build errors, please include the actual error (in full, complete, unedited, copy-pasted as text) in the question body.

Comment: Oh sorry. It makes a runtime error.

Comment: "xvalue so it's lifetime is prolonged" that would be a misconception. C++ prolongs lifetimes of *temporaries*, not lvalues, rvalues or prvalues. It does so when a reference is bound to such a temporary object. There is no temporary object in your expression. Moreover, `bar` and `baz` both invoke undefined behaviour, one by returning a reference to a local object and the other by failing to return anything.

Comment: @n.m. `x` is *not* local.

Comment: @n.m. - `bar` returns a reference to a static at file scope.

Comment: @StoryTeller sorry you are right of course. No UB in bar.

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings.

Comment: C++ prolongs the lifetime of temporary objects [when bound to **`const`** references](https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88).  No magic happens for mutable references.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I think the return value of `baz()` would be xvalue, so its lifetime is prolonged.

At first what `baz()` returns is always a dangling reference.

For `int&& baz() { return 10; }`, the [lifetime of the temporary](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary) is not extended. It's constructed inside the function and will be destroyed when get out of the function, then `baz()` always returns a dangling reference.

> a temporary bound to a return value of a function in a `return` statement is not extended: it is destroyed immediately at the end of the return expression. Such function always returns a dangling reference.

Then for `int&& rr5 = baz();`, `rr5` is a dangling reference too; deference on it leads to [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and anything is possible.

On the other hand, if you change `baz()` to return-by-value, everything would be fine; the return value is copied and then bound to `rr5`, then the lifetime of the temporary is extended to the lifetime of `rr5`.

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/FTB14070)

Comment: Shouldn't it be saved in `rr5` before the temporary is destroyed?

Comment: @CinCout It would have to be `moved` in the `baz()` function in order to do that

Comment: @CinCout - `rr5` doesn't store anything. It's bound to an object. That object is essentially destroyed before the binding even happens.

Comment: It means a function returning rvalue is only useful when it uses `std::move()` in returning?

Comment: Is `int&& baz() { 10; }` now equivalent to `int&& baz() { return 10; }`? I must have missed that improvement in C++...

Comment: @n.m. I suppose it's a typo (which is fixed in the 2nd code snippet).

Comment: @CinCout As others said, the point is that the temporary is constructed inside the function, and destroyed when function returns, before being bound to `rr5`.